# follow up on R# warning: Possible 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Tags: c#, resharper

I have the following expression, where `a.AnswerId` is of type `long?`. ReSharper warns of a possible `InvalidOperationException` in the select function. Is there ever a case where this could actually happen? (corner-cases are fine too)

```
long[] ids = answers.Where(a => a.AnswerId.HasValue)
                    .Select(a => a.AnswerId.Value)
                    .ToArray();
```

Comment: You can track when these issues are addressed by following these two issues on the JetBrains issue tracker: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-213609 http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-200225

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you check in the `Where` that `a.AnswerId` has a value, `a.AnswerId.Value` will never throw an `InvalidOperationException` (unless another thread is changing the data at the same time). Resharper has pretty good code analysis capabilities, but it can't spot everything, and in this case it doesn't realize that the `Where` makes it safe to call `.Value` in the `Select`, hence the warning. So you can safely ignore this warning.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, ReSharper often comes up with false positives. In this case, there won’t be a problem as long as `AnswerId` returns the same value in the calls to `Where` and `Select`. (Make sure `AnswerId` doesn’t have some crazy implementation that returns a number the first time you access it and `null` the second time.)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, ReSharper cannot track condition checks through LINQ lambdas sequence. This is a known problem.