# Select nonNullable values of nullable property from collection of objects with PLINQ

Tags: c#, linq, plinq

Why when i use Plinq in query such as

```
var notNullParameterValues = (from operation in operations.AsParallel()
                        where operation.NullableParameter.HasValue
                        select operation.NullableParameter.Value)
                        .Distinct().ToList();
```

resharper warn me with 'possible System.InvalidOperationException'?

For simplicity operations is `IList<Operation>;`

```
public class Operation 
{
    public int? NullableParameter {get; set;}
}
```

update: Thank you all for answers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965915/follow-up-on-r-warning-possible-system-invalidoperationexception

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because Resharper is not perfect?

I am sure it is also suggesting to check if operation is null.

take a look [JetBrains Issue Tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-335638)

Answer (score 0):

```
var notNullParameterValues = (from operation in operations.AsParallel()
                              let nullableParameter = operation.NullableParameter
                              where nullableParameter != null
                              select nullableParameter.Value).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: i currently using that solution)